# How to deal with Choice Type with an Entity as options in Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I have two entities that are : Classroom and Student. With a ManyToOne relationship. When creating a new student, i use a form with classroom as a choicetype:

```
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($classes as $c){
        $arr[$c->getNom()]="true";
    }
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($student)->add('nom', TextType::class)
            ->add('classe',ChoiceType::class,array('choices'=>$arr))
            ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array('label'=>'Enregistrer le niveau'))
            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

The twig file code is this:

```
  {{ form_widget(form.classeroom,{'attr':{'class':'form-control input-rounded'}}) }}.
```

The question is after submitting the form, i don't know how to get the classeroom id to give it to the student. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, i found the answer

Comment: please, add the answer or delete this question.:)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you're using the wrong Type. Instead of ChoiceType use EntityType
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($student)->add('nom', TextType::class)
                ->add('classe',ChoiceType::class,array(
                     'class' => 'AppBundle:Youclass',
                     'choice_label' => 'nom',
                     // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
                     // 'multiple' => true,
                     // 'expanded' => true,
))
                ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array('label'=>'Enregistrer le niveau'))
                ->getForm();
```